# Picking primes to use for Halton Sequences in R

Tags: r, random

I'm trying to generate some two-dimensional Halton Sequences in R, and am using the `randtoolsbox` package. It seems as if this function defaults to choosing 2 and 3 as the prime bases, but I'd like to generate sequences using others. The documentation does not indicate (as far as I can tell) any way of setting this option.

Does anyone know of a way, using `randtoolsbox` or another package, of generating Halton Sequences in R based on user-chosen prime bases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I ended up just programming my own function for this. It's probably not going to be fast for super large `n`, but it allows you to pick your own prime bases, anyway:

```
gHalton <- function(n, prime) {
    # define function which generates value of halton
    # sequence at given n
    halton_single_number <- function(n, prime) {
        n_0 <- n
        hn <- 0
        f <- 1/prime
        while(n_0 > 0) {
            n_1 <- floor(n_0/prime)
            r <- n_0 - n_1*prime
            hn <- hn + f*r
            f = f/prime
            n_0 = n_1
        }
        return(hn)
    }

    # create 0 vector of desired length
    vector <- rep(0, n)

    # fill vector
    for(i in 1:n) {
        vector[i] <- halton_single_number(i, prime)
    }

    return(vector)
}
```

Other answers or more efficient functions are certainly welcome. Maybe this will be of use to someone in the future, in any case.